How to make a bullet point in a List of HTML5 behave like a hyperlink?
I have the following HTML5 code:
<h3> Los primeros tres</h3>
<ul>
    <li>El Duelo</li>
    <li>Fundación</li>
    <li>El Péndulo de Foucault</li>
</ul>

I need the bullet points to behave like a hyperlink, just the bullet point, not the text. I am only able to make the whole thing a hyperlink, but not just the bullet point. I just want to use HTML and CSS, not Javascript or something more complicated.
I search the web and only found how to make the entire thing a hyperlink.
Thanks in advance.

Try adding an anchor tag which a bullet point symbol.
See this example:


li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: skyblue;
}

a::before {
  content: "•";
}

a:active {
  color: blue;
}
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#home"></a> Home
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#about"></a> About
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#contact"></a> Contact
  </li>
</ul>




But how did you enter that symbol? That bullet point?

@Feuergeist you can copy it by searching on internet, or you can use the HTML entity &bull;

@Feuergeist these special icons are classified in glyph-icons. Ass SioGabx has suggested, you can simply search for bullet point glyph or type the entity code. Either way here is the symbol: •

And how can I change the color of a glyph-icon?

I have edited the answer with the changed color of the symbol
